# Finding the image and the inverse function of $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus \{1\} \to \Bbb C$,$f(z)= \frac {1+z} {1-z} $ on the domain $\Omega$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a function  $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus \{1\} \to \Bbb C$ defined by $f(z)= \frac {1+z}  {1-z}$ and I have to find:

1) The image of the function under the domain $\Omega =[z=x+iy$ when $x,y \in \Bbb R |$ $ |z|^2<1 , y>0] $

2) An inverse function $g: f(\Omega) \to \Omega$ such that $f \circ g = g \circ f = Id$

What I`ve tried:
1) I wrote the function with $x$ and $y$ so I got: $f(x,y)= \frac {1-(x^2+y^2)} {(1-x)^2+y^2}+i \frac {2y}{(1-x)^2+y^2}$
I want to look only in the Boundary $\partial \Omega$ and somhow to imply it on $\Omega$
if $|z|=1$ I got that only the Imaginary part is stay- so all the imegimary numbers are included so $ f(x,y) = i\frac {2y}{1-2x}$.
but when $y=0$ I got only the real part $ f(x,y)= \frac {1+x} {1-x}$ so $f(x,y)>0$

I think the answer of the first is $f(\Omega)=[z| Re(z)>0]$ but I not quiet sure...

2) I found the inverse function by switching the roles of $z$ and $f(z)$ and got
$ g(f(z))= \frac {f(z)-1}  {f(z)+1} $ but I don`t understand how to relate this to the domain $\Omega$.. I be glad for help..

Comment: What is $\mathbb{C}/1$?

Comment: all the complex numbers without 1+i0

Comment: Don’t mix up / with \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine the inverse, set $z = \frac{1+w}{1-w}$. Then $z - zw = 1+w$ and $w(1+z) = z-1$. Hence, the inverse of $f$ is $$g(z) = \frac{z-1}{1+z}.$$

To determine the image of $\Omega$, write $z = r e^{i\vartheta}$, where $0 \leq r < 1$, and $0 < \vartheta < \pi$. Then $$f(z) = \frac{1+re^{i\vartheta}}{1-re^{i\vartheta}}.$$ Can you deduce the image from the following information:

- If $r =0$, then $f(z) =1$.
- If $r \to 1$, then $f(z) \to \dfrac{1+e^{i\vartheta}}{1-e^{i\vartheta}}$. Moreover, if $\vartheta \to 0$, $f(z) \to \infty$, and if $\vartheta \to \pi$, then $f(z) \to 0$.
- Möbius transformations map generalised circles to generalised circles, where a generalised circle is either a circle or a line.

Comment: I need the inverse function of the image of $\Omega$ not a general one...

Comment: I think that as I wrote f(z) is getting all the imaginary numbers, but the real numbers must be positive